# Does C# Development Environment affect User Capability

Tags: c#

I'm on a Mac so I have to use GTK# to build my C# app in Visual Studio. Does that affect the audience's capabilities if they are on a Microsoft device? Does the development environment/libraries available on one OS restrict the user? I am new to C# development...obviously.

Comment: This isn't about C#. It is about the tradeoffs of multiplatform development. If you target multiple platforms, you can't use platform-specific features.

Comment: Thanks. So I am restricted in what I can build because of this limitation, so any development would be quite basic to be functional of different devices, or may not even work on some devices.

Comment: Basically. It all depends on what your developing. The choice of whether to write a platform specific app or multi-platform app or to write multiple apps is something that cannot be decided in a generic way.

Comment: I will consider purchasing a Windows device in that case. I don't think I can even connect to SQL with GTK# on the Mac. I think I need .NET.

Comment: While running a SQL Server might be a lot trickier on Mac, there is no reason you can not connect to a SQL Server from Macintosh. Networking does not care for the OS of the target System, unless extra work is made to create a personal Protocoll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically boils down to picking the right Framework. There are 3 big choices: .NET Framework, Mono, .NET Core. In all of them you have different Display technologies and classes can behave totally differently. As such you should pick your framework as the first choice. Porting between them is not a trivial task.

While Platform independance was a original goal of .NET, it never quite materialised for the **.NET Framework**. My best guess is that it simply grew too big to be ported. It has the most Display Technologies avalible, but some of them are no longer being developed.

While no Platform independance was comming from Microsoft, people developed the **Mono** Framework. It is missing large parts of the classes.

Finally MS got their act together and they brought out **.NET Core**. This is much more succint then the somewhat bloated .NET Framework. Also this time the Platform Independance did appear. There are official installers for Linux and Mac.

If you are developing on a Mac, then that means you only really have Mono and .NET Core avalible. Depending on the OS version, maybe even only Mono. From here it splits on what your Frontend/GUI is going to be: Desktop Application, Computergame, Dynamic Webpage, App for the MS or Android Store, App for the Mac Store.

Comment: Yes I need to upgrade Mac OS as I can't install .NET Core on 10.11.6, only Mono, which I have been developing in with restrictions. All very helpful information. Thanks Christopher and Aluan Haddad.